# Como posso resolver erro "The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<int>' " - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sha-256

**Estou tentando buscar um Token da API usando Flutter, mas esse código:**

```
var _random = Random.secure();
var random = List<int>.generate(32, (i) => _random.nextInt(256));

var verificador = base64Url.encode(random).replaceAll('+', '-').replaceAll('/', '_').replaceAll('=', '');

var base64ToSha256 = sha256.convert(verificador);//erro aqui

var desafio = base64Url.encode(base64ToSha256).replaceAll('+', '-').replaceAll('/', '_').replaceAll('=', '');
```

Mas não estou conseguindo usar o sha256.convert

Erro exibido: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que você esteja usando a lib `crypto`.

Você está passando uma String para o sha256:

```dart
var base64ToSha256 = sha256.convert(verificador);
```

Mas na verdade ele aceita uma lista de bytes, que são representados em int. Então é necessário fazer o encode para utf8 (que retornará uma `List<int>`):

```dart
var base64ToSha256 = sha256.convert(utf8.encode(verificador));
```

Comment: Valeu Julio obrigado pela explicação.  Mas agora estou com outro problema ._.

Comment: A parte: `var desafio = base64Url.encode(base64ToSha256)` está com esse erro `The argument type 'Digest' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<int>'` qual serio o método para corrigir? Deu uma pesquisada sobre esse erro mas não encontrei muita coisa (na real não encontrei nada)

Comment: Qual implementação/lib vc está usando para o sha256?? É basicamente o mesmo problema, vc está tentando passar um tipo `Digest` para um método que aceita uma Lista de int.

Comment: import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';

Comment: Ok, então o objeto `Digest` possui um atributo `bytes` que é uma lista de int. Então faça: `var desafio = base64Url.encode(base64ToSha256.bytes)`